# PHP Connection To Azure-SQL Database

Tags: php, azure

In the below code, I try to connect to an azure-sql database with PHP, and in the first part of the if, I write out if the connection failed, which I don't receive.  In the next else, I write out if the connection passed, which I get the message on ("Connection succeeded").  This appears to connect correctly; however, I do get an output of `0` even though it clearly hits this part of the else.  I can't tell from research if 0 means success, but if it the connection failed, wouldn't it hit the first part of the if?

The problem is that this code isn't outputting the array column added to the string, so it appears that while it's registering as succeeding, it's actually failing, or something else is wrong, like the syntax.

```
<?php 

    /// Test variable
    $writeOutResult = "Result:  ";

    /// VARIABLES NOT INCLUDED

    /// Connect
    $connInfo = array("Database"=>$azureDB
            , "UID"=>$azureUser
            , "PWD"=>$azurePass
            , "MultipleActiveResultSets"=>true
        );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($azureServer,$connInfo);

    /// Test connection
    if($conn === false)
    {
        //FatalError("Server unavailable.");
        $writeOutResult = "Connection failed.";
    }
    else
    {       
        echo "Connection succeeded";
        $get = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $writeOutResult += $row["Column"];
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<p>Output:</p>
<?php 
    echo $writeOutResult;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your variable `$query` is a valid SQL stmt? And could you query the data directly use the `$query` stmt in SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no obvious error on PHP. I tested on my side and which worked fine.

It could be the case of following causes, you can check one by one.

- Please check the SQL query stmt, whether it's correct, you can query it in SSMS for verification.
- Check the value and data type. Whether it can be plus directly.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.