# Linux Wordpress Can't Communicate With Azure-SQL Database?

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

[See this question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371560/php-connection-to-azure-sql-database).

After spending time troubleshooting this issue, it appears that there's no way for a LAMP server with Wordpress to communicate with an Azure-SQL database, or if there is already a library for this:

- What is the library?
- Where would I add this reference?
- Is an install needed, or a reference needed?

I've read the MS Azure documentation, but the errors I'm getting about failed references indicate that they are either using a *WAMP server* or they are skipping the step of *adding the required references*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use your Azure database with vanilla PHP via [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php), but WordPress doesn't support SQL Server. From [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases):

> Currently, the official WordPress distribution only supports the MySQL and MariaDB database engines.

Note that MariaDB is a drop-in fork of MySQL. The same functions are used with both, so WordPress really only supports a single type of database server.

Comment: This is the take-away from one of those links: `The SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows.`